# Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod: One or more errors occurred. (Response > status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: powershell, powerbi, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I try to get Power Bi transactions in PowerShell but got 401 unauthorized error.

I run first the commando '**Login-PowerBIServiceAccount**' and the browser opened automatically to sign in with my serviceaccount. I sign in and run the script below:

```
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/SOME-GUID/dataflows/SOME-GUID/transactions' -Method GET
```

Then I got this error:

> Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod: One or more errors occurred. (Response
> status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).)

Which permissions do I need to give my self to run this script?

Comment: You have an issue with the Route not having the authorization for the Role.  Your account has on the server a Role to allow you to access the route (the URI after the api.powerbi.com).  See Role on following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-power-bi-security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.profile/connect-powerbiserviceaccount?view=powerbi-ps) for authentication.

$tenantId = "xxx"

$appId = "xxx"

$clientSecret = "xxx"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientSecret -Force -AsPlainText

$credential = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential($appId, $securePassword)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $credential

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $getWorkspacesUrl -Method Get